# What's the most efficient way to replace old locomotives in OpenTTD

Tags: openttd

I have a bunch of trains transporting coal back and forth and I wanted to know what's the most effective way to replace a locomotive when it expires.

Right now I tell it to stop at the depot, sell it, buy the new one, and tell it to go again (by telling it to stop at the depot for maintenance if necessary). It is a bit painful if you have 10 trains to replace. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an option to [autoreplace](http://wiki.openttd.org/Replace_vehicles#Autoreplace) trains when they go for servicing. Go to the Trains menu and select the 'Replace vehicles' button (this is also possible for all other types of vehicles)

[image]

Then choose the train you have currently and its replacement, and select the 'Start Replacing Vehicles' option to start autoreplacement.

[image]

When all vehicles are replaced the old vehicle in the autoreplace list will be greyed out, and you can choose 'Stop Replacing Vehicles' to remove it from the list.

Comment: Don't forget that if you upgrade to a different type, like Electric or something, that the track has to be able to handle it, or you've just replaced it with a dead weight.

Comment: Also, if you have a 14 unit train (one engine) and replace the train unit with a double-headed train (and end up with 15 units) you may need to expand your stations to avoid a load time pentaly.

Comment: Worse, especially if you've taken over any competitors, your new trains might be too long to fit in the double-track segments.